# Spark org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException when calling .show() and .toPandas() with an S3 dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I created a PySpark DataFrame `df` with Parquet data on AWS S3. Calling `df.count()` works, but `df.show()` or `df.toPandas()` fails with the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0
 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 14, 10.20.202.97, 
executor driver): org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-
Length delimited message body (expected: 77,826,675; received: 8,192)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:198)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:228)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:172)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.abort(S3ObjectInputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.reopen(S3AInputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.seek(S3AInputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.seek(FSDataInputStream.java:62)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.H1SeekableInputStream.seek(H1SeekableInputStream.java:46)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$ConsecutiveChunkList.readAll(ParquetFileReader.java:1157)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readNextRowGroup(ParquetFileReader.java:805)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.checkRead(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:127)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:207)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have answered my own question below: Java update seems to be responsible for the problem. But can anyone solve this without downgrading Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens after the latest Java update (1.8.0_272). Reverting to 1.8.0_265 will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @mck - this is the only answer that helped me with the same error - can I ask how you found out this works?

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty one day all my code stopped working, and the only thing that changed is the java version (auto system upgrades), so I thought downgrading would help

Comment: @mck I have same error but I have tried with all java version (8u272, 282, 265), nothing works. Any idea what could be wrong? Something worth noting is, read works for very small files, but for files in MBs it fails.

Comment: @AvikAggarwal are you sure you selected the java version correctly? Did you change the java_home path?

Comment: @mck yes, JAVA_HOME's value is being correctly set, since the read is working for files in KBs of size but fails for MB-sized files.

Comment: I'm not sure how you had multiple java installations with different versions. Maybe something is wrong when you're changing the java versions.

Answer (score 1):

1. File a bug report on issues.apache.org for HADOOP and include the stack trace. Connection errors during abort() should be discarded *as it is trying to close the HTTP connection anyway*.
2. upgrade your hadoop-* jars to a more recent version (ideally, 3.1+) with the shaded httpclient libs